# Extracting hashtags from .txt file python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

So I started a TikTok tool for data analysis but I cannot extract hashtags from a saved .txt file. Here there's what I did:

```
from tiktok_bot import TikTokBot  # TikTok API
import csv
import os 
import sys
import re # attempt to use findall, but it didn't work

try:
     os.mkdir("./data") . # Creating data folder
except OSError as e:
   print("Directory exists")


def getData(): # date in file name
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime ("%Y-%m-%d")

def buildFileName(type): # building .csv name
    return ("./data/") + getData() + (type) + ".csv"

def buildText(type): # building .txt name
    return ("./data/") + getData() + (type) + ".txt"

with open(buildFileName("_shares"), mode='a') as csv_file:   # writing .csv file
    fieldnames = ['User ID', 'URL', 'Description', 'Comments', 'Likes']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for post in most_shared_posts:
        print(str(post.author_user_id) , str(post.share_url) , str(post.desc) , post.statistics.comment_count , post.statistics.digg_count)
        writer.writerow({'User ID': str(post.author_user_id), 'URL': str(post.share_url), 'Description': str(post.desc), 'Comments': post.statistics.comment_count, 'Likes': post.statistics.digg_count})

with open(buildFileName("_shares"), mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for lines in csv_reader:
      print(lines['Description'])     # save .csv
sys.stdout = open(buildText("_shares"), "w") . # .csv saved into .txt
print (lines['Description'])
```

What can I do now to extract hashtags from the descriptions printed in the .txt file?
Note: Description is made by .txt and hashtags, so basically I think is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
import re
m = re.findall(r'#(\w+)', lines['Description'])
print(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question but am I correct in assuming you want to get the hashtags from the description string? If so you can use re to find all hashtag words in the string.

```
hashtags = re.findall(r"#\w*", description)
```

This should return a list for what you're looking for

Comment: In my .csv file I saved all the descriptions (text+hashtags), then I "converted" .csv file in .txt and now I want to extract only the hashtags from the text file and save them in another text file called hashtags.txt